# Mongoose model.findOneAndUpdate returns TypeError: callFn.apply is not a function

Tags: node.js, mongoose, асинхронность

Начало документа

```
var mongoose = require( 'libs/mongoose' ),
    Schema = mongoose.Schema,
    async = require( 'async' ),
    AuthError = require( 'libs/errors' ).AuthError,
    Task = require( 'models/task').Task,
    authCheck = require( 'libs/auth' ),
    crypto = require( 'crypto' ),

    UserSchema = new Schema ({
        /* ..... */ 
    });
```

Следующий код просто замерзает

```
UserSchema.statics.addTasks = function ( task, callback ) {
    var User = this;
    async.waterfall([

        function ( callback ) {
            User.findById( task.userId, callback );
        },

        function ( user, callback ) {
            user.update( { $push: { tasks: task._id } }, callback );
        }
    ], callback );
};
```

Изменил стандартный callback на свой, бросает ошибку

```
UserSchema.statics.addTasks = function ( task, callback ) {
    var User = this;
    async.waterfall([

        function ( callback ) {
            User.findById( task.userId, callback );
        },

        function ( user, callback ) {
            user.update( { $push: { tasks: task._id } }, function ( err, user ) {
                console.log( arguments ); // { '0': null, '1': { ok: 1, nModified: 1, n: 1 } }
                return callback( err, user ); // TypeError: callFn.apply is not a function
            } );
        }
    ], callback );
};
```

Метод `User.addTask` вызываю тоже в цепочке async,

попытка заменить данный метод на одну функцию

```
User.findOneAndUpdate(/*...*/)
```

зависает на callback -е, а в случае замены стандартного на свою функцию бросает

> callback is not a function

Comment: Не отметил еще одну важную вещь, в случае обновления без оператора $push функция работает нормально